# Erro ao executar js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho o código js (abaixo) para trocar o nome de um link, porém o script não funciona. E quando faço no console funciona normalmente. Alguém pode me dizer o que seria? O script está no final do documento html.

```
<script>
    var texto = "ADICIONAR";    
    var x = document.querySelectorAll('.glis-thickbox.tb-added.qvBinded');
    x[0].innerHTML = texto;
</script>
```

Tenho o seguinte erro :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Código html:

```
<div class="insertsku-popup">
    <a id="6db09796a68f4625b293b54a7c6432e0" href="#" class="glis-thickbox tb-added qvBinded">
        Insert in my list
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Provavelmente o seu seletor esta errado. Tenta alterar a linha do selectorAll para `var x = document.querySelectorAll('.glis-thickbox .tb-added .qvBinded');`

Comment: Coloca o html na pergunta também.

Comment: Assim não funcionou nem no console.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Não, com ou sem espaços são coisas bem distintas. Sem espaço o seletor buscará o mesmo elemento que possui todas as classes informadas. Com espaço, o seletor será de elementos filhos, buscando a classe `qvBinded` dentro de um elemento com a classe `tb-added`dentro de um elemento com a classe `glis-thickbox`.

Comment: @Gustavo, tente colocar seu código JS dentro do evento `onLoad` do HTML. Assim você garantirá que o JS seja executado apenas quando o DOM estiver carregado.

Answer (score 0):

Este erro acontece porque você provavelmente está apresentando o bloco de javascript antes mesmo de apresentar o elemento no html e espera que estaja disponível no `DOM`, logo `var x` não está definida e não representa um objeto expondo o atributo `innerHtml` que você tenta acessar na linha seguinte. O resultado é a mensagem de erro apresentada:

**Veja a reprodução do erro abaixo:**

```html
<script>
    var texto = "ADICIONAR";    
    var x = document.querySelectorAll('.glis-thickbox.tb-added.qvBinded');
    x[0].innerHTML = texto;
</script>

<div class="insertsku-popup">
    <a id="6db09796a68f4625b293b54a7c6432e0" href="#" class="glis-thickbox tb-added qvBinded">
        Insert in my list
    </a>
</div>
```

**Para corrigir o problema:**

Você , simplesmente, pode adicionar o bloco de javascript ao final do documento, porém o mais adequando é você esperar o carregamento do documento ou da própria janela, para aí sim manipular o `DOM`. E se lhe interessa apenas a primeira ocorrência, não faz sentido percorrer todo o modelo como `querySelectorAll()` para acessar o primeiro item, ainda sem validar se algum foi encontrado o que resultaria em outro erro diferente.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var texto = "ADICIONAR";    
    var x = document.querySelector('.glis-thickbox.tb-added.qvBinded');
    
    if(x != null)
      x.innerHTML = texto;
}
```

```html
<div class="insertsku-popup">
    <a id="6db09796a68f4625b293b54a7c6432e0" href="#" class="glis-thickbox tb-added qvBinded">
        Insert in my list
    </a>
</div>
```